# Text moving between table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableview with multiple sections and different number of rows in each section.

I created a custom table view cell. The cell has a label and a textfield.

This same custom cell is used for every cell in the table view.

When I enter a value in the textfield it appears in some of the other textfields as well in other rows. And sometimes the text disappears from the textfield I entered it in and appears in the row below. This happens as I scroll the tableview up and down.

This is the code I use for cellForRowAt

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:   "LabelTextFieldTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LabelTextFieldTableViewCell
    for i in approachSection {
        if Int(i.row) == indexPath.row {
            cell.myLabel.text = i.name
            cell.myTextField.placeholder = cell.setPlaceholder(type: i.type!)
            if i.type != CustomFieldType.text.rawValue {
                cell.isInteger = true
            }
        }
    }
return cell
```

And the Custom Cell is

```
class LabelTextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

    var isInteger: Bool?
    var type: String!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        myTextField.delegate = self
        myTextField.textAlignment = .right
        myTextField.borderStyle = .none


    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setPlaceholder(type: String) -> String {
        switch type {
        case CustomFieldType.count.rawValue:
            return "#"
        case CustomFieldType.time.rawValue:
            return "Time as 1234"
        case CustomFieldType.text.rawValue:
            return "Enter Text"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.textColor = .black
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard textField.text != "" else { return }

        if isInteger != nil {
            guard checkIfIntegers(str: textField.text!) != false else {
                print("Not all Integers")
                textField.textColor = .red
                return
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: bcoz of `dequeueReusableCell`, in UITablview your cell is being reused, so when you enter text in any one textfield, it will appear in cell at different index.

plus I suggest you that first learn basic of UITablview, there are lots of tutorial.

Comment: I think you should keep track of the cell in which the text field has changed. And each time you cellForRow is called, you make sure the textfield is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the prepareToReuse method in your cell subclass. Here you should reset all the values to default and in the corresponding cellForRowAtIndexPath method set the appropriate values to cell.

```
func prepareForReuse()
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

write this method in your `LabelTextFieldTableViewCell` class
i hope it will help you
happy coding =)

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you are following this algorithm correctly

1. First of all, you will decide how many sections you need?
2. then you will decide how many rows in a section you need
3. then you will assign each row your data source model from the cell, for that you don't have to use for loop. Index.row will do that job for you.

Note: you can use switch statements within the these methods to decide how many rows to show in which specific section.

```
- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: // required method

– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: // required method

– numberOfSectionsInTableView:

– sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:

– tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:

– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:

– tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
```